# CMS running on top of Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Does anyone know of any free/opensource/commercial CMS products (ASP.NET or MVC-based) that use Azure Table or BLOB Storage for their back-end?

Thanks!

Comment: We're using SQL Azure for ours, but unfortunately it's vertical-market-specific. What drives your question?

Comment: I need bigger scale than SQL Azure can accomodate

Comment: Entirely reasonable, I think we're going to have to do something similar ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

you could also use umbraco and deploy it with the azure accelerator! i have used it in the past and really liked it:

http://waacceleratorumbraco.codeplex.com/

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with his question.

Comment: really?  umbraco uses SQL Azure and Table storage for their backend.. so how is that not answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

Igorek. Thats what I will do for http://www.webnodes.com/ when I start there December 1st, check back later on.